# How to make a distinction between omitted parameter and parameter default value

Tags: c#

I am writing a method (let's call it 'Bar') which accepts many parameters. For convenience sake, I set a default value so developers don't have to specify a bunch of 'null' when invoking my method. In other words, my method's signature looks like this:

```
public void Bar(string paramA = null, string paramB = null, ... many more parameters omitted...)
```

The code in my method checks for a null value and ignores the parameter in that case. However, there are some situations where I need to make a distinction between a 'default' null value and a null value deliberately set by the developer.

Here are two sample calls to illustrate what I'm talking about. The first one omits all parameters (and therefore the C# compiler will replace them with null at compile time) and the second sample the developer has decided to specify 'null' for the first parameter.

```
Bar();
Bar(null);
```

I have found several articles that talk about using "Option/Some/None" pattern. The best one, in my opinion, is [here](http://twistedoakstudios.com/blog/Post1130_when-null-is-not-enough-an-option-type-for-c).

But I am struggling to figure out how I can still provide a 'default' value for developers' convenience. Conceptually, I would like to write something like this:

```
public void Bar(Option<string> paramA = Option.None)
```

but the C# compiler complains that 'Option.None' is not a compile-time constant.

Comment: If you've got "many parameters", there's very often a parameter class struggling to get out that you can initialize with properties at will (and those you don't assign are left at their defaults). This does not require any funky `Option` classes either. And it won't break if you need to change defaults in the next version.

Comment: Or you can add an additional parameter `bool useA = true` and if user don't want to use A, he can set `useA` to `false`. However, in practice, you are better to add some overload or use a class a parameter as other people have suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's essentially what Nullable is for.  Although it is used for structs you might create your own wrapper class that does the same thing (with cast operators and such).

For example, you could create Argument<T> that looks and acts like a T but has a property called Set that returns a bool.

Then you could define your method:

```
public void Bar(Argument<string> paramA = null, ...)
```

Here's a full example, but I have to admit I'm not happy with it.  It seems I can't get the implicit cast operator to be honored when passed as an argument.  I had thought C# added this kind of coercion a few years back when they did covariant and contravariant casts.  Maybe I misremembered.  So it still requires a cast (which I'm doing through an extension method).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calling Foo(default(string).ToArg())...");
        Foo(default(string).ToArg());

        Console.WriteLine("Calling Foo(((string)null).ToArg())...");
        Foo(((string)null).ToArg());

        Console.WriteLine("Calling Foo(\"test\".ToArg())...");
        Foo("test".ToArg());

        Console.WriteLine("Calling Foo()...");
        Foo();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void Foo(Argument<string> arg1 = null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("arg1 is {0}null", arg1 == null ? "" : "not ");
        Console.WriteLine("arg1.IsSet={0}", arg1?.IsSet ?? false);
        Console.WriteLine("arg1.Value={0}", arg1?.Value ?? "(null)");
    }

}

public class Argument<T>
{
    public Argument()
    {
        IsSet = false;
    }

    public Argument(T t)
    {
        _t = t;
        IsSet = true;
    }

    private T _t;

    public T Value { get { return _t; } set { _t = value; IsSet = true; } }
    public bool IsSet { get; private set; }
    public static implicit operator T(Argument<T> t) { return t._t; }

}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static Argument<string> ToArg(this string s) { return new Argument<string>(s); }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

C# has the concept of "overloads", which are C# methods with the same name but with different parameters.

```
private void MethodA(string param1) {

}

private void MethodA(string param1, string param2) {

}
```

If this is not what you want, you could also use the builder pattern. The `Builder` could be a struct to reduce memory allocations, if you worry about that kind of thing.

```
var result = new Builder()
  .SetParam1(value)
  .SetParam2(value)
  .Build();
```

Comment: Unfortunately i have too many parameters to consider overloads. The number of overloads would not be manageable. However, I need to look into your 'builder' suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way to distinguish them.  In fact, the "default" value is baked into the call by the compiler, so

```
Bar();
```

and

```
Bar(null);
```

result in equivalent IL.

Normally I would recommend overloads instead of defaults but since you have several parameters the number of overload would grow exponentially.

If you need to distinguish between `null` and a "default" value then you need to use something else as a default.

Another option would be to create a type that could store all parameter values.  Then you can tell if a "parameter" was *set* to null versus being null  by default since you can hook into the property setters.

Comment: You're probably right: my best option is probably a class to store all parameters

Answer (score -2):

Depending on the type, you would do something like this:

```
public static void Bar(string a = "", int b = 0) {
```

because they are both no value, but still nullable optionally.
For boolean values, I would just default to false, since boolean values are non-nullable. 
so:

```
public static void Bar(string a = "", int b = 0) {
if (a == "") {
// if there is no parameter
}
else {
// stuff
}
if (b == 0) {
// no param
}
else {
// stuff
}
```

Hope I helped!

Comment: I'm sorry, I fail to see how your suggestion helps me differentiate between an omitted parameter and a parameter that was intentionally set to null.